# Select individal colums when fetching data from a database

Tags: php, html, database

I've just started learning PHP so this is quite a struggle for me, any help is appreciated!

So, I've managed to select my database, table and get data from it. But I need to select more data from the older columns.

Here is some of the code:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username FROM interview");

while($rowval = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

 {
   $username= $rowval['username'];
   $username2= $rowval['username'];
   $username3= $rowval['username'];
   $username4= $rowval['username'];


}


?>
```

And I am displaying the data in a button, I want $username to display the first column and $username2  to display the second column etc...

I fetch the data using this code:

```
<?php echo  $username; ?>
<?php echo  $username2; ?>
<?php echo  $username3; ?>
<?php echo  $username4; ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Someone said do col1, col2, col3, and then do $username1= $rowval[col1]['username']; but that does not work?

Comment: What does the database table look like?

Comment: It pretty much sounds like you are confusing _columns_ with _rows_.

Comment: And no, you do not want "numbered" variable names. You want to use an array, that you put the values in inside the loop over the _rows_ in the result set, so that later on you can easily access them via their numeric index inside that array.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you re-factoring your "while" loop the following way for better scalability:

```
$usernames=array();
while($rowval = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

 {
   $usernames[] = $rowval['username'];
 }
```

Then, you'll be able to access usernames like:

```
echo 'The first user name is: '.$usernames[0];
echo 'The second user name is: '.$usernames[1];
echo 'The third user name is: '.$usernames[2];
```

Comment: Hey I did this, but when I refreshed my page it was just white I guess that means it crashed?

Comment: @Jack Smith I believe you may copied it wrong. Have you got some debug info in your error_log file?

Comment: No ahah, sorry like I said I'm really new to PHP

Comment: How do I make this?

Answer (score 0):

My php skills are a bit rusty, so take this with a grain of salt:

At first it is important to get the language right. A database table consists of rows and columns, the columns are the ones you select with the the part after the `SELECT` statement, if you write `SELECT username` what you select is the username column.

```
SELECT username FROM interview;
```

So if you want to select more columns from your table you have to put them in your `SELECT` statement. Let's say you want to select the username and the status of the interview, you would need to include the status in your `SELECT` statement like this:

```
SELECT username, status from interview;
```

Then you can access the interview status just like you did it with the username.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username, status from interview;");

while($rowval = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $username= $rowval['username'];
    $status = $rowval['status'];
}
```

Remember that what you get as the `$rowVal` is just a single **row** of your table. So if you want to collect all usernames and statuses from your table you have to use a datastructure to collect them.

```
$queryResult = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username, status from interview;");
$result = array();
while($rowval = mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult))
{
    $username= $rowval['username'];
    $status = $rowval['status'];
    // With this action we build an array, that has each row's result as value.
    $result[] = array('username' => $username, 'status' => $status);
}
```

To access the results you can then query the `$result` array like this:

```
// The interview status of the first entry in your table
$result[0]['status'];
```